# Shisha Ve'esrim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twenty-six?

### ?שישה ועשרים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 326? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 326, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

... and when you're thinking that lazy gematria will produce an answer that's good, or even funny or invigorating? Just remember, you ain't [Rabbi Akiva](http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.58.3), and this isn't #127.

Comment: Someone else can do the exact math on this to get it to come out properly, but I believe that if you say kaddish for 11 months, and the length of the year is just right (and you possibly start at the right time of year), you can get 354-28=326 days of saying kaddish.  Alternatively:  Rosh Chodesh Elul?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Malbim Yechezkel 42:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39980&st=&pgnum=257) says that the outer courtyard from North to South measured 326 Amos.

חלל החצר החיצונה מצפון לדרום מבואר שהיה שכ"ו אמה, כי מבואר למעלה (מ' י"ט כ"ג) שמדד מקיר החצר החיצונה עד קיר החצר הפנימי לצפון ולדרום מאה אמה בכל צד, הרי מאתים אמה, וחלל החצר הפנימי מאה. (כמש"ש פסוק מ"ז), ושני קירותיו היו כ"ו אמה (כמש"ש פסוק ו' שכל קיר היה י"ג אמה), ס"ה שכ"ו אמה. ומוכרח אצלי שכן היה גם כן אורך חללו ממזרח למערב

Comment: This is the outer courtyard of the Third Temple, right? So shouldn't it be "will measure"?

Comment: It sounds to me of the previous temple. מבואר שהיה שכ"ו" אמה". Shehaya means it was. If it is talking about the future temple it would say Sheyiye.